# How do you display a filtered list based on a state created with use state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I have some code [in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-bush-7x0qd) that is made up of 4 divs, 2 with the category "Book" and 2 with the category "Article". Some buttons at the top should trigger if all the divs should be displayed, only the books, or only the articles. All the buttons show every div currently, so the page doesn't change and it looks like the state stays the same

---

Here is the code which is on the sandbox

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
/* import Container from './design/Container' */

import Test from "./Test";
const posts = [
  {
    title: "React Hooks",
    content: "The greatest thing since sliced bread!",
    category: "Book"
  },
  {
    title: "Using React Fragments",
    content: "Keeping the DOM tree clean!",
    category: "Article"
  },
  {
    title: "Angular Hooks",
    content: "The greatest thing since sliced bread!",
    category: "Book"
  },
  {
    title: "Angular Fragments",
    content: "Keeping the DOM tree clean!",
    category: "Article"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [productItems, setProductItems] = useState(posts);

  function handleButton(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value === "All") {
      setProductItems(posts);
    } else {
      setProductItems(
        posts.filter((p, i) => <div key={i}>p.category === e.target.value</div>)
      );
    }

    setProductItems(posts);

    console.log(productItems);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Test posts={productItems} handleButton={handleButton} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Test.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Post({ p,title, content, category }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      
      <div>
        <h3>{p.title}</h3>
        <div>{p.content}</div>
        <br />
        <i>
          in <b>{p.category}</b>
        </i>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
export default function Test({handleButton, posts = [] }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <button value="All" onClick={handleButton}>
          All
        </button>
        <button value="Book" onClick={handleButton}>
          Book
        </button>
        <button value="Article" onClick={handleButton}>
          Article
        </button>
      </div>

      <div>
        {posts.map((p) => {
          return <Post key={p.title} p={p} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**style.scss**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few things wrong, one was that you handleButton required an argument but you weren't passing one to it. You need to call it like `onClick={(e) => handleButton(e)}` another was that you set the state of product items again after your if statement. You had already set it to the filtered value, but then you overwrote it with the unfiltered value like `setProductItems(posts);` so you have to remove this line. Another was that your filter function didn't really make sense. I would look it up and learn more about it. It takes a function that returns a boolean; it doesn't return a div.

---

**SOLUTION**
([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sunset-b9unc?file=/src/Test.js:0-718))

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Test from "./Test";

const posts = [
  {
    title: "React Hooks",
    content: "The greatest thing since sliced bread!",
    category: "Book"
  },
  {
    title: "Using React Fragments",
    content: "Keeping the DOM tree clean!",
    category: "Article"
  },
  {
    title: "Angular Hooks",
    content: "The greatest thing since sliced bread!",
    category: "Book"
  },
  {
    title: "Angular Fragments",
    content: "Keeping the DOM tree clean!",
    category: "Article"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [productItems, setProductItems] = useState(posts);

  function handleButton(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value === "All") {
      setProductItems(posts);
    } else {
      setProductItems(posts.filter((p) => p.category === e.target.value));
    }

    console.log(productItems);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Test posts={productItems} handleButton={handleButton} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Test.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Post = ({ pa }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <h3>{pa.title}</h3>
        <div>{pa.content}</div>

        <i>
          in <b>{pa.category}</b>
        </i>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ({ posts = [], handleButton }) => (
  <>
    <div>
      <button value="All" onClick={(e) => handleButton(e)}>
        All
      </button>
      <button value="Book" onClick={(e) => handleButton(e)}>
        Book
      </button>
      <button value="Article" onClick={(e) => handleButton(e)}>
        Article
      </button>
    </div>

    <div>
      {posts.map((pa, i) => (
        <Post key={i} pa={pa} />
      ))}
    </div>
  

</>
);
```